# pyaudio воспроизвести аудио

Tags: python, аудио, pyaudio

У меня есть такой простенький класс. Метод play должен воспроизводить запись. Он вроде работает, запись(точнее filename) воспроизводится, но сообщение 'Stop' некогда не выводится.
Как это исправить?

```
class utils:
    def play(self, filename):
        wf = wave.open(filename, 'rb')
        p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        stream = p.open(format=
                        p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                        channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                        rate=wf.getframerate(),
                        output=True)
        data = wf.readframes(1024)
        while data != '':
            stream.write(data)
            data = wf.readframes(1024)
        stream.close()
        p.terminate()
        print('Stop')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поменяйте `while data != ''` на `while data`. Это более общая булевая проверка, сгодится для пустых строк, байтов, массивов и т.п.

Вообще, судя по флагу `rb` у вас из файла считываются **байты**, а проверка на пустую **строку**.

Comment: спасибо, не заметил. Просто взял код от сюда и подогнал под мою задачу. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951046/how-to-play-an-audiofile-with-pyaudio

Comment: @Nikto, посмотрел, там последние два комментария говорят про ту проверку :)